# Generating random data at 1 minute intervals: Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have created a spline real time chart where I want to show points at regular intervals.

Every point is an event taking place after one minute. However I am having a hard time trying to understand all the moving pieces:

1. the interval function on the highchart demo I referred updated every 1 second, I have made that 6000.
2. the dummy updating in the javascript just takes the latest time and appends it, is there supposed to be some delay introduced there?
3. the dummy initialization data in series has a for loop which again I could not understand. I understand that javascript produces a UNIX timestamp and its millisecond manipulation however the default code (again slightly modified from a highchart demo) runs from -9999 to 0 and multiples by a number.

I want to understand these parts and make sure that every time my x axis 'ticks' towards the right, I have a one minute gap and only one point on the graph.

PS: Please forgive any missing brackets, they might have been missed while posting the question, but I assure you that it isnt a problem.

Here is my code for series:

```
           series: [{
                type: 'spline',
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function () {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -9999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push([
                            time + i * 60000,
                            Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 10
                        ]);
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]
```

Here is my code for the chart:

```
chart: {
 events: {
           load: function () {

             // Set up the updating 
             var series = this.series[0];

             setInterval(function () {
               var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
               y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 10

               series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
             }, 6000);
           }
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your questions:

1. If you want to have 1 minute data interval, you need to use `60000` value (60 * 1000), `6000` milliseconds is 6 seconds.
2. Current date in the interval function is taking every `6000` milliseconds, which causes gaps in the data every `6000` milliseconds.
3. That data initialization depends on subtracting multiples of six seconds from the current timestamp:

---

```
data: (function() {
    // generate an array of random data
    var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

    for (i = -9999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        if (i === -500) {
            console.log(time, i, 60000); // 1560941909847 + (-500 * 60000)
            console.log(time + i * 60000); // 1560911909847
        } else if (i === -499) {
            console.log(time, i, 60000); // 1560941909847 + (-499 * 60000)
            console.log(time + i * 60000); // 1560911969847
        } else if (i === 0) {
            console.log(time, i, 60000); // 1560941909847 + (0 * 60000)
            console.log(time + i * 60000); // 1560941909847 = actual time
        }
        data.push([
            time + i * 60000,
            Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 10
        ]);
    }
    return data;
}())
```